Typescript doesn't warn me when I add additional property to a type
I have this
export enum ProfileFollowingViewModelType {
  Loading = 'FOLLOWING_LOADING',
  FollowingLoaded = 'FOLLOWING_LOADED',
}

export type ProfileFollowingViewModel =
  | {
      type: ProfileFollowingViewModelType.Loading;
    }
  | {
      type: ProfileFollowingViewModelType.FollowingLoaded;
      following: {
        id: string;
        username: string;
        profilePicture: string;
        followersCount: number;
        isFollowedByAuthUser:boolean
        link: string;
      }[];
    };
export const createProfileFollowingViewModel =
  () =>
  (): ProfileFollowingViewModel => {
    const areFollowingLoading = Math.floor(Math.random());

    const following = [{id:'test-id',username:'test username',profilePicture:'test.png',followingCount:0,followersCount:0,isFollowedByAuthUser:true}];
    if (areFollowingLoading)
      return { type: ProfileFollowingViewModelType.Loading }
    return {
      type: ProfileFollowingViewModelType.FollowingLoaded,
      following: following.map((f) => {
        return {
          id: f.id,
          username: f.username,
          profilePicture: f.profilePicture,
          followersCount: f.followersCount,
          isFollowedByAuthUser: f.isFollowedByAuthUser,
          link: `/u/${f}`,
        };
      }),
    };
  };

I can't remove an existing property in the following map that is in the type ProfileFollowingViewModel but I can add one without error.
Why is that?
edit: answer suggest that type declaration are open to extra properties but in this case why I have an error when I do this for exemple :
  const foo = ():{id:string,username:string} => { return {id:'boo',username:'bar',extra:'should not be here '}}

edit: after some test, it seem the map is the issue, if I remove the map and replace it with a hard coded object, it does throw me an error:
 following: [{id:'tt',
        username:'stst',
        followersCount:0,
        profilePicture:'',
        isFollowedByAuthUser:
        true,link:'',
        test:'should not be here'}]


• Please [edit] so your code is a [mre] where we can copy and paste it into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now this is full of errors you're not asking about, because of undeclared things that are private or third-party. So I can't see what's going on here and I'd have to just guess, and any answer you get will be people guessing.  I'd guess that you've run into this issue but without a [mre] I can't be sure.  • Also please [edit] to change "variable" to "property", assuming I understand correctly.

@jcalz,  I don't really understand the link with the other question. I showed here that when I repalce the map() with an hard coded array, the error show up, so typescript is checking for excess properties, no ? I understand that type are open to extra properties but why it depend of the way I return data here ?

Excess property checks only happen in specific circumstances involving object literals being assigned directly to a type that doesn't expect the excess properties. Values returned from functions (like the map callback) don't currently get such checking. The answer to the other question goes into significant detail with sources, so I'm not sure I can say anything here that isn't written there. Let me know if you have a more specific question.

As explained structural typing makes types open (extra properties are allowed).
You could use satisfies to limit allowed props:
return {
      type: ProfileFollowingViewModelType.FollowingLoaded,
      following: following.map((f) => {
        const user = selectUser(f, rootState);
        return {
          id: user.id,
          username: user.username,
          profilePicture: user.profilePicture,
          followersCount: user.followersCount,
          isFollowedByAuthUser: user.isFollowedByAuthUser,
          link: `/u/${f}`,
        };
      }),
    } satisfies ProfileFollowingViewModel


Neither, as long as you provide at least one of the required properties, ts should not raise an err(yell at you, lol). Typescript uses structural type system - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html
